# Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 14.23.5.2854 won't load my mcmod.info file

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

For some reason, Forge won't load my mcmod.info file, even though its formatted correctly and inside the src/main/resources folder.

mcmod.info:

```
[
  {
    "modid": "vanilext",
    "name": "vanillaextensions",
    "description": "Placeholder",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "mcversion": "1.12.2",
    "url": "",
    "updateUrl": "",
    "authorList": ["GermanBucket"],
    "credits": "",
    "logoFile": "",
    "screenshots": [],
    "dependencies": ["Forge"]
  }
]
```

my main class:

```
@Mod(modid = ConstRef.modid, version = ConstRef.version, name = ConstRef.name, useMetadata = true)
public class VanillaExtensions {

    private static Logger logger;
    @Mod.Instance
    private static VanillaExtensions instance;
    public static VanillaExtensions getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    @SidedProxy(modId = ConstRef.modid, serverSide = "mod.germanbucket.vanilext.proxy.CommonProxy", clientSide = "mod.germanbucket.vanilext.proxy.ClientProxy")
    private static CommonProxy proxy;
```

(This is with the import and the initialization phases cut out)

ConstRef:

```
public class ConstRef {
    public static final String modid = "vanilext";
    public static final String version = "1.0.0";
    public static final String name = "vanillaextensions";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can add these things at the bottom of `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
    main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir }
}
```